# Recursive algorithm solving by iteration method

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Consider the following recursive algorithm for computing the sum of first n squares Sum (n)=1square+2square+.......n square.
Algorithm:

```
int Sum (n) {
    if (n=1) return 1 ;
    else return sum (n-1)+n*n;
}
```

Write relation for above algorithm and solve it by iteration method.

Comment: Can`t solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Think about replacing `call sum(n-1)` with `(n-1)*(n-1)` for `n = n-1` and so on. So your iterative algo should be something like:

```
sum = 0
for (i from 1 to n)  
do
    sum += i*i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int add(int n);
 int main()
  {
   int n;
   printf("Enter an positive integer: ");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   printf("Sum = %d",sumofsquare(n));
   return 0;
 }
int sumofsquare(int n)
 {
if(n>1)
 return n*n+sumofsquare(n-1);  /* recursive call */
else if (n==1)
return 1; 
  }
```